# Bug?: The Playlist List API doesn't return the right thumbnails

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using a WordPress plugin called WP YouTube Lyte, which internally uses the YouTube Data API v3. I've however noticed that the for playlists, the featured thumbnail simply doesn't match the one that is set on YouTube itself.

I've dug down a bit deeper and made direct API calls myself, to notice, that it wasn't a bug in the plugin, but rather in YouTube's API.

Here I've used the API explorer with the following [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7EpZck9oTXT3z3DslPZQkXeKbEvqV840):

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet%252Cid&id=PL7EpZck9oTXT3z3DslPZQkXeKbEvqV840&_h=3&

In the thumbnails object, I am expecting the current featured playlist thumbnail, but instead in most cases, the API returns the thumbnails of the second video in the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the API's own documentation w.r.t. playlist's thumbnails (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#snippet.thumbnails) does not define/specify such concept as *featured thumbnail*.

Indeed Youtube's site itself is using internally the same API, but please bear in mind that Google's systems are distributed and highly asynchronous -- therefore I find it acceptable to observe such differences as yourself noticed, as long as the API documentation is not specifying tighter guarantees.